# Get fields from DataContext class, but exclude related tables

Tags: c#, linq, reflection, datacontext

I'm trying to iterate through a class T, which may or may not be a LINQ DataContext class.  It works for normal classes, but when passing in a database class from a Linq data context, it also iterates over the related tables with their related properties (like a deep copy).

I'm trying to just get all the "primitive" fields if it's a database class.  I.e. it should return all the fields in the table.
I've tried to filter on `IsPrimitive()`, but it does not return all the fields (it might for example exclude nullable int32's amongst others).  I've also tried using things like `BindingFlags.Public` and/or `BindingFlags.Instance` but to no avail.

```
public static T MyClone<T>(T original)
{
    T newObject = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(original.GetType());

    foreach (var originalProp in original.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        //Do something
    }
```